# Trouble Parsing XML File Using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, manifest

I'm trying to parse an XML manifest file for an Articulate eLearning course (imsmanifest.xml).

An excerpt of the XML structure is provided below (I'm trying to drill down to adlcp:masteryscore):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" version="1.0" identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3">
    <metadata/>
    <organizations default="Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG">
      <organization identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG">
        <title>Electrical Design - Part 3</title>
        <item identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3_SCO" identifierref="Articulate_Presenter_RES" isvisible="true">
          <title>Electrical Design - Part 3</title>
          <adlcp:masteryscore>65</adlcp:masteryscore>
        </item>
      </organization>
    </organizations>
    <resources/>
</manifest>
```

I've tried using XML::Simple and XML::LibXML. I can get these modules to work fine with simpler XML files, but not the manifest file I actually need to parse.

The following code shows my attempt to use XML::LibXML to drill down to the title tag:

```
use XML::LibXML;
$filename = "imsmanifest.xml";
$parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($filename);

for my $sample ($xmldoc->findnodes('/manifest/organizations/organization/item/title')) {
    for my $property ($sample->findnodes('./*')) {
        print $property->nodeName(), ": ", $property->textContent(), "\n";
    }
    print "\n"; 
};
```

How does one deal with the colon in the adlcp:masteryscore tag? Whenever I try to use this, I get an error - but maybe I'm not doing it right.

Could someone please show me the correct way to drill down to adlcp:masteryscore?

Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It's not going to make any real difference here, but you're running with scissors without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking to locate elements named `manifest` in the null namespace, but you want elements named `manifest` in the `http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2` namespace.

Fixes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $xml_qfn = 'imsmanifest.xml';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( no_network => 1 );
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($xml_qfn);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( a => "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" );
$xpc->registerNs( i => "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" );

for my $item ($xpc->findnodes('/i:manifest/i:organizations/i:organization/i:item', $doc)) {
    my $title   = $xpc->find('i:title/text()', $item);
    my $mastery = $xpc->find('a:masteryscore/text()', $item);
    print "$title: $mastery\n"; 
}
```

Note: The actual choice of prefix for use in an XPaths (`a` and `i`) is arbitrary. You can pick whatever you want, just like when you compose an XML document.

Note: I added `no_network => 1` to prevent libxml from fetching the DTDs every time you parse the XML doc.

Answer (score 0):

step one, fix your example so it is properly formed xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd" version="1.0" identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3">
    <metadata>
    <organizations default="Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG">
      <organization identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG">
        <title>Electrical Design - Part 3</title>
        <item identifier="Electrical_Design_Part_3_SCO" identifierref="Articulate_Presenter_RES" isvisible="true">
          <title>Electrical Design - Part 3</title>
          <adlcp:masteryscore>65</adlcp:masteryscore>
        </item>
      </organization>
    </organizations>
    <resources/>
</metadata>
</manifest>
```

fire up the perl debugger

```
DB<2> use XML::Simple

  DB<3> $x=XMLin("example.xml")

  DB<4> x $x
0  HASH(0x2733c48)
   'identifier' => 'Electrical_Design_Part_3'
   'metadata' => HASH(0x2733828)
      'organizations' => HASH(0x2733288)
         'default' => 'Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG'
         'organization' => HASH(0x272d7e8)
            'identifier' => 'Electrical_Design_Part_3_ORG'
            'item' => HASH(0x27285f8)
               'adlcp:masteryscore' => 65
               'identifier' => 'Electrical_Design_Part_3_SCO'
               'identifierref' => 'Articulate_Presenter_RES'
               'isvisible' => 'true'
               'title' => 'Electrical Design - Part 3'
            'title' => 'Electrical Design - Part 3'
      'resources' => HASH(0x27333d8)
           empty hash
   'version' => 1.0
   'xmlns' => 'http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2'
   'xmlns:adlcp' => 'http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2'
   'xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
   'xsi:schemaLocation' => 'http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd'

  DB<6> x keys %$x
0  'xmlns'
1  'xmlns:xsi'
2  'identifier'
3  'version'
4  'metadata'
5  'xsi:schemaLocation'
6  'xmlns:adlcp'
  DB<9> x keys %{$x->{metadata}}
0  'resources'
1  'organizations'
  DB<10> x keys %{$x->{metadata}{organizations}}
0  'default'
1  'organization'
  DB<11> x keys %{$x->{metadata}{organizations}{organizations}
Missing right curly or square bracket at (eval 22)[/usr/share/perl/5.14/perl5db.pl:640] line 4, at end of line
syntax error at (eval 22)[/usr/share/perl/5.14/perl5db.pl:640] line 4, at EOF
  DB<12> x keys %{$x->{metadata}{organizations}{organizations}}
  empty array
  DB<13> x keys %{$x->{metadata}{organizations}{organization}}
0  'identifier'
1  'item'
2  'title'
  DB<14> x keys %{$x->{metadata}{organizations}{organization}{item}}
0  'identifier'
1  'identifierref'
2  'isvisible'
3  'title'
4  'adlcp:masteryscore'
  DB<19> x $x->{metadata}{organizations}{organization}{item}{'adlcp:masteryscore'}
0  65
  DB<20>
```

so all you have to do is

```
use XML::Simple;
$x=XMLIN("example.xml");
print $x->{metadata}{organizations}{organization}{item}{'adlcp:masteryscore'};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That fails as soon as a second organisation or item is added. That fails if a given document uses `foo:masteryscore` instead of `adlcp:masteryscore`, which is completely acceptable. You should NEVER rely on the prefix, only the namespace. XML::Simple is the hardest XML parser to use.

Answer (score 0):

the xml is not valid, you need to close the tags metadata and resources

after that XML::Simple will work with this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;


use XML::Simple qw(:strict);

my $ref = XMLin('test.xml',ForceArray => [], KeyAttr => {});
print STDERR Dumper $ref;
```

Comment: This is very hard to do with XML::Simple. It considers `foo:masteryscore` to be different than `adlcp:masteryscore`, when they could very well be the same. XML::Simple is the hardest XML parser to use.